# knockoutjs mapping. I can't get my json to hook up properly and into a select dropdown

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new to knockout and mvc. I tried to look at many of the documentation from knockout and pluralsight but i can't seem to put everything together.
Here's what i have:
I have a json data coming back from my api :

```
[{
ID: 1,
LongName: "My Long Name",
ShortName: "Long",
Rank: 10
},
{
ID: 2,
LongName: "My second long name",
ShortName: "Short",
Rank: 20
}]
```

In my javascript i have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("../api/myData", function (data) {
            alert(data[0].ID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to create a dropdown menu that gets populated from my json data (longname and id). When the user selects, another menu dynamically gets populated base on the selection.
Also do I use the Knockout mapper script?
Please help.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample fiddle that may help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/LpwgQ/

The UI starts by loading `Options` dropdown via an AJAX call.  Once it has loaded you can select one of the options, which will trigger the loading of the sub options.  Choose Option 1 and it will load one set of sub options, switch to Option 2 and it will load a different set of sub options.  Switch the initial options back to its 'default' and the second menu will disappear.

In my code I do make use of the `mapping` plugin.  It makes the job of transforming your returned JSON into observables and observableArrays very easy.  Whether you should use it, or not, is up to your requirements.

--

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'LongName', optionsValue: 'ID', value: selectedOption, optionsCaption: '-Select-'"></select>
```

You map the returned options to a select using Knockout bindings.  See [Options Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for details.  `options` points to the array of choices, `optionsText` tells Knockout which property to use as the text and `optionsValue` will populate the value, `value` is the observable that Knockout will set when an option is chosen, and `optionsCaption` provides text when no choice has been made.

By subscribing to `selectedOption` you can react when it changes, making another AJAX call if desired to load the sub options.

JS

```
self.selectedOption.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // Reset the suboptions
    self.suboptions([]);

    // If we have selected an option go get the suboptions
    if (newValue) {
      ...
    }
});
```